# update a common object, with async worker, with comparison php

Tags: php, algorithm, mongodb, redis, locking

I want to describe a complex way of builder an intelligent basket (like for shop).

If I want to create an app, that will find me the cheapest ingredients of a recepee.

let's say a tomotato pasta dish recepee.

my basket will be like that

```
|-pasta
|-tomoto sauce
|-parmesan
|-meet
```

let's say you've several supplier for each element that will bring you each one of the ingredient, or several.

I can have up to 10 php workers, that will work async to find each cheapest ingredient price.

how would you managed your basket data, in order to be sure that any worker will always put the cheapest price in the good case (ingredient) without loosing data from another worker.

It's a very abstract problem, I will not work with ingredients, and will need to keep more data than just a double(price). But the idea will be exactly the same.

Problems:

1- if you store an object in redis, take it out, update the price of pasta, maybe, in the same time another worker has taken out the same object to update the price of parmesan. where the price of parmesan can be update several times as we have several suppliers that are selling parmesan.
2- If I'll work with lock, I'll have all the time worker that are 'blocked' on a process, and won't continue to work on something else.

Any idea to manage those complex situation ?
Which data storage to use ? Redis/memCached/mongo ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: How about creating a sortable in-memory index per each worker?

Comment: Sounds to me like a typical trade-off issue(like any race issue). You need to choose between  accuracy to speed.